# How to separate Hyper-V Private network from the External network

Tags: domain-name-system, hyper-v, dhcp, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I am setting up a virtual test lab and I configured a domain controller VM running Windows 2008 R2 on my Hyper-V 2008 R2 server. I needed to download and install updates on it so I added an External NIC adapter and got that done. However, systems on my actual real physical domain were pulling IPs from this server and that was a big oopsy on my part so I immediately removed the External NIC adapter until I could find out how to go about keeping the Private and the External separate. If someone from the Server Fault community can help with this since I am pretty new to this, I would be very grateful. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Just turn off the DHCP service.

Comment: I am actually trying to set up an SCCM virtual test lab so I dont think turning off DHCP services would be wise since I am going to be testing OSD which requires PXE services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any valid reason that you would need the DHCP service running in this lab so my suggestion would be to turn it off or remove that role.

That being said, if for some reason you do need the DHCP service in the lab environment then you'll need to isolate the lab network in order to prevent the DHCP broadcasts (during the DHCP DORA process) in the production network from reaching your lab VM by either putting the lab on an isolated switch or configuring a separate VLAN for the lab in your current switching environment. If you need internet access as well then that's going to entail some additional work at the router layer.

If you don't need internet access and don't need access to the production network then you can create an Internal virtual network in Hyper-V for Host and VM communication or a Private virtual network for VM only communication.

Comment: I am following Microsot test lab guides in order to set up my virtual SCCM 2007 R3 environment so I do need a DHCP for this from what I am reading. I dont need internet connection at this time, but it would be nice to have to update my virtual app server until I can get a virtual WSUS server setup. Right now, I have an External, Internal and Private network but my DC VM is only using the Private and my app server is using the Private and the Internal so I can grab files off of the host server. Should I check the "Enable virtual LAN identification for management operating system" box? Thanks

Comment: Okay, I must have been smoking crack when i asked this because I realize that in order to do what I am asking i would have to have my netwwork engineering team set up my virtual environment on a completely different VLAN so as not to screw with the production environment. Since this will not be possible, I will just set up and configure an internal WSUS eventually. So, joeqwerty, you are definite right about that. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help...